# It can't emit particles with animation node

Tags: animation-nodes

The emitter can emit particles when it's not connected to animation node. but when I connect it to the animation node with position transforming, the particles can't fly, they all are stick to the emitter object.

Anything I missed or any suggestion? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender's particle system integrator resets the simulation every time an unexpected change in the object's transformation happen. Try moving the object mid-simulation and you will find that the particles resets. As far as I know, to work around this, you need to bake the animation into key-frames so that Blender's know about the transformation in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I clicked the "bake to keyframes", but it's not working neither. the timeline is not written to "red".

Comment: I found it only work when I do this way: step1) run with "auto execution" enabled      step2) disable "Auto Execution" .       step3) bake .  Is that a right approach?

Comment: @blackgun Yes, you have to disable auto-execution in the second run, otherwise baking to keyframes would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

I detail here the solution found by @blackgun and following @Omar Emara's reasoning

In the Node Tree panel we can see that Auto Execution is always activated. For the particles of the emitter object to "fly" in the scene we must first bake the displacement of the emitter object by adding keyframes to the timeline with their locations.
Then we go out with Esc and run the animation again but disabling the Auto Execution option. Now the particles leave the emitter object and "fly" through the scene: they are no attached to the object.
I publish a gif of the process.

[image: Particles moving with emmiter working in Animation nodes]