# Animation Nodes: Create a trail effect from an object moved by a list of coordinates

Tags: animation, node-editor, particles, animation-nodes

I have a list of coordinates in a CSV file and my goal is to be able to animate the movement of an animal or vehicle in Blender.  An example of what I want to achieve can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUBUTCL0JVI&feature=emb_logo). Notice that the movement of objects leaves a light effect on the track that fades over time. In [this other example](https://youtu.be/hW_4c3PFrOs), the same effect is shown but this time the trail is maintained and does not fade.

[image]

I am learning Animation Nodes and can already move a sphere by parsing the CSV and capturing the coordinates from a list. Here's my node tree. It works just fine.

[image]

Also, I've experimented with applying particles to the emitting object and having them [fly around the scene as the object moves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155049/it-cant-emit-particles-with-animation-node/196248#196248).
But I would like to create a trail effect on the movement with Animation Node as the examples show.  I have seen several solutions to create trails in Blender, using particles or using splines, but I don't know which is the best solution. Also, in all solutions the movement of the emitting object is already predefined by keyframes or is random, but it is not given by a list of coordinates.

I am blocked. How can I create an animation in Blender with a trail that follows a list of coordinates?